# How can a function with an embedded function be compiled?

Tags: compile

Compile fun continues today, and I'm trying to get the function below to compile.  First the function:

```
NewC[ymax_, xmax_] := Block[{x1, a2, a0, b0, a1, b1, c1, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3, C0, xb = 0, xe = 100, ve},
  a3 = (xmax + ymax - 100)/(2*(xe - xmax)*(xe - xmax));
  x1 = (200 - xmax - 2*ymax + 2*a3*xe*(xe - xmax))/(2*a3*(xe - xmax) + 1);
  a2 = -(2*a3*(xe - x1) + 1)/(2*(x1 - xmax));
  b2 = -2*a2*xmax;
  b3 = -1 - 2*a3*xe;
  a0 = -(xb + ymax)/((xmax - xb)*(xmax - xb));
  b0 = -2*a0*xmax;
  C0 = ymax + a0*xmax*xmax;
  a1 = (100 - xe - ymax)/((xe - xmax)*(xe - xmax));
  b1 = -2*a1*xmax;
  c1 = ymax + a1*xmax*xmax;
  c2 = ymax + a2*xmax*xmax;
  c3 = a3*xe*xe + 100;
  ve2[ym_, tnlr_] := If[ym <= ((100 - xmax) + (100 - xe))/2,
  If[tnlr <= xmax, a0*tnlr*tnlr + b0*tnlr + xb, a1*tnlr*tnlr + b1*tnlr + c1],
  If[tnlr <= x1, a2*tnlr*tnlr + b2*tnlr + c2, a3*tnlr*tnlr + b3*tnlr + c3]];
  ve = Chop[Map[ve2[ymax, #[[1]]] &, $range] // N]
 ]
```

So pretty straight forward, except for the embedded function. So I externalize the important parts and global variable, but have no idea how to handle the embedded function.

Here's what I tried:

```
NewC = With[{$range = $range, xb = 0, xe = 100},
   Compile[{{ymax, _Real, 1}, {xmax, _Real, 1}},
    Block[{x1, a2, a0, b0, a1, b1, c1, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3, C0, ve,ve2},
   a3 = (xmax + ymax - 100)/(2*(xe - xmax)*(xe - xmax)); 
   x1 = (200 - xmax - 2*ymax + 
     2*a3*xe*(xe - xmax))/(2*a3*(xe - xmax) + 1);
   a2 = -(2*a3*(xe - x1) + 1)/(2*(x1 - xmax));
   b2 = -2*a2*xmax;
   b3 = -1 - 2*a3*xe;
   a0 = -(xb + ymax)/((xmax - xb)*(xmax - xb));
   b0 = -2*a0*xmax;
   C0 = ymax + a0*xmax*xmax;
   a1 = (100 - xe - ymax)/((xe - xmax)*(xe - xmax));
   b1 = -2*a1*xmax;
   c1 = ymax + a1*xmax*xmax;
   c2 = ymax + a2*xmax*xmax;
   c3 = a3*xe*xe + 100;
   ve2[ym_, tnlr_] := If[ym <= ((100 - xmax) + (100 - xe))/2,
     If[tnlr <= xmax, a0*tnlr*tnlr + b0*tnlr + xb, a1*tnlr*tnlr + b1*tnlr + c1],
     If[tnlr <= x1, a2*tnlr*tnlr + b2*tnlr + c2,a3*tnlr*tnlr + b3*tnlr + c3]];
   ve = Chop[Map[ve2[ymax, #[[1]]] &, $range] // N]
   ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
```

Certainly not the winning ticket.  So are there principles to follow when this type of function must be modified?  Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is `$range` and does it ever change?  Should it be an input to the function or a global variable?

Comment: $range is a list of values from 0-1 and is a global variable used in other functions as well.  Thanks!

Comment: You are `Map`ing `#[[1]]` onto `$range` so I assumed that it was a matrix, not a vector (or it was a vector of vectors).  Also, I just noticed `Curve2` vs `ve2`.  Is this a typo and are these two the same?  I assumed that they are in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a general solution, but it should apply to your example.  For a general solution the question is going to be: what does the function depend on?

First let's get a few things out of the way: `$range` appears to be a global variable, possibly a matrix where you only use the first column.  Instead let's make `range` represent only the first column (a simple vector of numbers) and let's make it an input to the function.

The key operation is the mapping.  It map a pre-constructed function.  We can exploit the fact  that `Function` objects can usually be compiled without problem, and write the function in that form.  Also, we must avoid assigning the function to a variable name and write it directly in the `Map`.

Here's the result:

```
cf = Compile[
  (* the inputs; range is also an input, I assume it's a vector of reals *)
  {{ymax, _Real}, {xmax, _Real}, {range, _Real, 1}},

  (* no changes here: *)  
  Block[{x1, a2, a0, b0, a1, b1, c1, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3, C0, xb = 0, xe = 100, ve}, 
   a3 = (xmax + ymax - 100)/(2*(xe - xmax)*(xe - xmax));
   x1 = (200 - xmax - 2*ymax + 2*a3*xe*(xe - xmax))/(2*a3*(xe - xmax) + 1);
   a2 = -(2*a3*(xe - x1) + 1)/(2*(x1 - xmax));
   b2 = -2*a2*xmax;
   b3 = -1 - 2*a3*xe;
   a0 = -(xb + ymax)/((xmax - xb)*(xmax - xb));
   b0 = -2*a0*xmax;
   C0 = ymax + a0*xmax*xmax;
   a1 = (100 - xe - ymax)/((xe - xmax)*(xe - xmax));
   b1 = -2*a1*xmax;
   c1 = ymax + a1*xmax*xmax;
   c2 = ymax + a2*xmax*xmax;
   c3 = a3*xe*xe + 100;

   (* embed the function in the Map directly, as a Function[...] expression *)
   Chop@Map[
    Function[tnlr,
     If[ymax <= ((100 - xmax) + (100 - xe))/2, 
       If[tnlr <= xmax, a0*tnlr*tnlr + b0*tnlr + xb, 
          a1*tnlr*tnlr + b1*tnlr + c1], 
       If[tnlr <= x1, a2*tnlr*tnlr + b2*tnlr + c2, 
          a3*tnlr*tnlr + b3*tnlr + c3] ]],

    range]
  ] (* end Block *)
 ] (* end Compile *)
```

This compiles without issues.

Comment: If you needed to map this function multiple times, and thus couldn't avoid naming it, compiling it would be a more difficult problem ...

Comment: Looks like the last line of the function is missing, can I just add it in as is?

Comment: @RHall The last two lines are hidden in the code block, did you scroll down?  It looks pretty confusing on a Mac where the scrollbars are not shown ... EDIT: I removed some whitespace to make it shorter now.

Comment: @RHall `Chop` is okay because it is compilable, though you could just apply `Chop` outside of the compiled function.  But `N` should not be used.  It is not compilable and it is not needed here.  `range` is going to be converted to machine precision numbers (the same thing `N` does) anyway before it's passed to the compiled function internally and the result is also going to be a packed machine precision array.

Comment: Correction to "`N` is not compilable": the compiler recognizes that `N` is not needed and will automatically remove it if you do add it.

Comment: I see it, thanks.  Getting an error "The comparison, LessEqual, is invalid for tensor arguments"

Comment: @RHall What are your input types?  I assumed that `xmax` and `ymax` are real numbers and `range` is a vector of reals.  `cf[1,1,Range[1,2,.1]]` works.

Comment: Yes of course your right.  I used $range as input but found it needed to be flattened for the compiled function.  Works very well!  Thanks for the tips and help!